# Check that two file exists in UNIX Directory

Tags: linux, unix, ksh

Good Morning,

I am trying to write a korn shell script to look inside a directory that contains loads of files and check that each file also exists with .orig on the end.

For example if a file inside the directory is called 'mercury_1' there must also be a file called 'mercury_1.orig'

If there isn't, it needs to move the mercury_1 file to another location. However if the .orig file exists do nothing and move onto the next file.

I am sure it is really simple but I am not that experienced in writing Linux scripts and help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a small **`ksh`** snippet to check if a file exists in the current directory

```
fname=mercury_1
if [ -f $fname ]
then
  echo "file exists"
else
  echo "file doesn't exit"
fi
```

Edit:

The updated script that does the said functionality

```
#/usr/bin/ksh
if [ ! $# -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "provide dir"
    exit  
fi

dir=$1

cd $dir

#process file names not ending with orig
for fname in `ls | grep -v ".orig$"`
do
  echo processing file $fname
  if [ -d $fname ]  #skip directory
  then
    continue
  fi

  if [ -f "$fname.orig" ] #if equiv. orig file present 
  then
    echo "file exist"
    continue
  else
    echo "moving"       
    mv $fname /tmp
  fi

 done
```

Hope its of help!

Comment: This isn't the complete answer to OP's question!

Comment: hangon, my intention was to give a direction. I'll update the answer

Comment: sanjayk79 - I managed to get that far by myself, again its just the checking to see if it exists again with .orig in the end. I did see you said you were going to update it, so I look forward to that! Thanks!

Comment: @alyr1481 you need to skip directory while iterating check the edit i made.

Comment: @sanjayk79 Works a treat Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below script

**script.sh :**

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! $# -eq 2 ]; then
    echo "error";
    exit;
fi

for File in $1/*
do
    Tfile=${File%%.*}
    if [ ! -f $Tfile.orig ]; then
        echo "$File"
        mv $File $2/
    fi
done
```

Usage:

```
./script.sh <search directory>  <destination dir if file not present>
```

Here, for each file with extension stripped check if "*.orig" is present, if not then move file to different directory, else do nothing.

Extension is stripped because you don't want to repeat the same steps for **`*.orig`** files.

Comment: This does work exactly how i want it to, but it also seems to move folders that are in that directory is there a way to only do this on files?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this on OSX (basically mv should not differ to much from linux). My test directory is zbar and destination is /tmp directory

```
 #!/bin/bash
 FILES=zbar
 cd $FILES
 array=$(ls -p |grep -v "/")  # we search for file without extension so put them in array and ignore directory
 echo $array
 for f in $array #loop in array and find .orig file 
 do
 #echo $f
 if [ -e "$f.orig" ]
   then
   echo "found $f.orig"
 else
     mv -f "$f" "/tmp"
   fi
 done
```